# cannot create an instance in xaml in silverlight 4.0

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

In the xaml  code i  get an error telling  cannot create an instance  of 
this  AllEmployeeViewModel  class file, actually  this class file exists in the solution  folder when i  type scr: the intellsene shows me the class file

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <scr:AllEmployeeViewModel  x:Key="empName"></scr:AllEmployeeViewModel>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Background="White" Width="400"
    Height="407" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource empName}}" >
<Grid  x:Name="grdAllEmp" DataContext="{Binding Path=EmployeeClass}">
    <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="274" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,8,0,0" 
                    Name="dgEmployee" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="385"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    <Button Content="Get All Employees" Height="23" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,288,0,0" 
            Name="btnAllEmplloyees" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="381" 
            Command="{Binding  Path=DataContext.GetEmployees,ElementName=MainGrid}"/>
</Grid>
```

i  am trying to bind the data to grid, if  i ignore the compile time error and  run its gives an error key not found.

please let me know the  solutionif you know,working on this issue from past  2days

any help  would be great
thanks.

Comment: solution: InitializeComponent();
            if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
            {
                //Code that throws the exception
            }

Comment: You really need to post code with this question and your "fix". For instance exactly what code did you bypass with your not design mode check? Without clarification both your question and your answer are not useful.

Answer (score 4):

I too had the same issue. 
`cannot create instance of viewmodel`

Just copy this code and place it in ViewModel

```
public bool IsDesignTime
{
    get
    {
      return (Application.Current == null) || 
             (Application.Current.GetType() == typeof(Application));
    }
}




//Constructor    
public ViewModelClass()
{
    if(IsDesignTime == false)
    {
       //Your Code 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line in MainPage.xaml.cs page

```
InitializeComponent();
        if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        {
            //Code that throws the exception
        }
```

it works  fine.

Comment: You really need to post code with your question and this example of "a fix". For instance exactly what code did you bypass with your not design mode check? Without clarification both your question and your answer are not useful.

Answer (score 0):

Does your class `AllEmployeeViewModel` have a zero-argument constructor?  WIthout that, Silverlight cannot create an instance of your class.

Answer (score 0):

You have a binding to `EmployeeClass`. That has to be a collection of some type for this to work, but the name `EmployeeClass` sounds like a single object and not a collection.

You really needed to post your View Model code as we had to guess this.

I put together a quick example and if the ViewModel contains:

```
public ObservableCollection<EmployeeClass> Employees { get; set; }
```

and I populate them with a few sample EmployeeClass objects,

```
public AllEmployeeViewModel()
{
    this.Employees  = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeClass>();
    this.Employees.Add(new EmployeeClass() { Name = "One" });
    this.Employees.Add(new EmployeeClass() { Name = "Two" });
```

and I change the binding to:

```
<Grid  x:Name="grdAllEmp" DataContext="{Binding Path=Employees}">
```

It looks like this (no other changes):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, i will explain it to you hopefully it will help you.
In my **ViewModel**'s constructor i was executing some code, all code was withing below **if** condition except,

```
       If(!IsInDesignMode)
       {
             //  my code
       }

       //   Problamatic method execution point
```

Except a method that i wanted to execute every time, but it turns out that you can only execute code if above condition is satisfied else your view model instance will not be created.

So to avoid this you have to do like that:

```
       If(!IsInDesignMode)
       {
             //  my code
            //   Problamatic method execution point
       }
```

Put all your code inside that condition and everything will be fine.

**Note:** I was using **MVVMLight library** along with **Model-View-ViweModel** pattern.